# SQL Query on a synchronized Data Extension doesn't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

first of all, excuse my bad english :-)

I tried to get Data from a synchronized Data Extension in Marketingcloud and store it in a new Data Extension with an SQL Query in Automation Studio.
But i don't have the option to get Data from synchronized DE's. 
I only have access to my own Data Extensions.
The folder "synchronized Data Extensions" ist noch accessible.

Do you know, why i don't have access to synchronized Data Extensions?

My User has Admin Rights in Sales- and Marketingcloud.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you work in an environment with multiple Business Units? It is not unusual to connect the parent (ENT) BU with e.g. Service Cloud, and not child BU. Hence synced DEs will only be available in the ENT scope, and you will not see them in Contact Builder in your child BU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to run the query from a Synchronized Object? Do you have access to Contact Builder to check if there is any object Synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to allow sharing of synchronized data extension from the parent business unit. Go to contact builder and then synchronized data sources in the parent business unit. After selecting the synchronized object, click on its "sharing" option from where you can give its access to different child business units.

Hope this helps!